# How can `time` control other processes through a pipe?

Tags: time, pipe, sh

In the general case we have a command like `P | Q | R` which has the following semantics for the shell:

- Create a processes `P`, `Q`, `R`
- Bind the output of `P` to the input of `Q`
- Bind the output of `Q` to the input of `R`
- Bind the output of `P` to the shell input
- Bind the output of `R` to the shell output
- Run `P`, `Q`, `R`

This is cristal clear. But let's observe the following:

```
$ time echo lol | cat | wc -l
echo lol  0.00s user 0.00s system 10% cpu 0.005 total
cat  0.00s user 0.00s system 81% cpu 0.001 total
wc -l  0.00s user 0.00s system 83% cpu 0.001 total
```

Here we have time which works as it's perfectly aware of everything in the pipe, while from the syntax standpoint I would expect it to be only aware of `echo lol`, which would be launched — i guess — as subprocess.

This would be easily done if `time` was a shell builtin, but this is not the case, at least on my GNU/Linux operating system: `which time` gives me `/usr/bin/time`, and the `bash` manpage does not mention a `time` builtin.

I could not think of any other program which has similar characteristics. Is there a special exception for the `time` program or a very obscure system call which allows this kind of interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you showed for `time echo lol | cat | wc -l` does indeed require a `time` to be a shell builtin (actually something even more rare than a shell builtin: a keyword, like `if` and `for`.)

There are a couple of flaws in your investigation. First of all, you're not clear on what shell you're using. The specific format of `time` output in your example is generated by zsh, which has a `time` keyword. It's documented in zshmisc(1).

bash also has a `time` keyword, but it doesn't produce separate output for each command in the pipeline. It's hard to find in the bash man page because they neglected to list it among the other keywords, but it is explained under the heading "SHELL GRAMMAR", subheading "Pipelines":

> If  the  time reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as user and system time consumed by its execution are  reported  when  the pipeline  terminates.   The -p option changes the output format to that specified by POSIX.  The TIMEFORMAT variable may be  set  to  a  format string  that  specifies how the timing information should be displayed; see the description of TIMEFORMAT under Shell Variables below.

Your other error was using `which`, which you apparently did in bash, after running your example `time` command in zsh. In zsh there is a builtin `which` that can tell you about other builtins. In bash there isn't. So you ran an external command `which` that has no way of knowing what's built in to your shell; it can only tell you about the `time` it found in `$PATH`.

There are a few zsh builtins related to `which`; I like the `where` command, which lists *all* of the places a command is found, instead of just the one that is currently first in the search order. In bash you should use the `type` command to find out whether something is a builtin.

```
bash$ type time
time is a shell keyword
zsh% where time
time: shell reserved word
/usr/bin/time
```

**Note:** this answer is based on bash 4.1.17 and zsh 5.0.6 which are the versions I could easily test with. The answer would be more believable if there was some version of bash out there that duplicated the zsh `time` format, but as far as I know that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Let me bow in respect for your shell-fu.